# VuePress site generated by `vuepress build` doesn't call `mounted()` hooks when the `--debug` option is used (works fine with `vuepress dev`)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuepress

**EDIT: I originally thought the custom theme causes the error; I rephrased the question afterwards. Live demo is also fixed now.**

I created a custom theme for VuePress that extends the `@vuepress/theme-default` to add some new Vue components. All works fine when I use `vuepress dev`. However, when I create a site using `vuepress build`, there isn't *any* event listener attached, so e.g. the menu doesn't open when the button is clicked.

The [source code](https://github.com/ptandler/vuepress-theme-single-page-sections) can be found at github.

A [live demo](https://ptandler.github.io/vuepress-theme-single-page-sections/) is also available there: You can inspect the menu button there (at `#app > div.theme-container.sections-layout > header > div.sidebar-button`) - and compare it to the one at https://vuepress.vuejs.org/.

The problem seems to be that the `mounted` hooks are not executed in the version created by `build`. However, the [docs say that browser API access](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/using-vue.html#browser-api-access-restrictions) should happen in `beforeMount` or `mounted` hooks. So this sounds that this is the place to use.

Any suggestion?

I'm using VuePrss cli.js/1.2.0 win32-x64 node-v12.13.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem wasn't caused by the custom template, but by using the `--debug` option together with `vuepress build`. This obviously causes errors.

Well, if you read the [VuePress CLI documentation](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/api/cli.html#debug) carefully, you might notice that this option is intended for development server only ...